# Подскажите, какой тип придаточного

Tags: синтаксис

**"Я знаю всё, что ты не знаешь!"**

Думаю, что изъяснительное, ведь вопрос "что". Я знаю (что) что ты не знаешь.

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна, а какая классификация придаточных принята в учебнике, который Вы используете? Какие виды придаточных в ней упомянуты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Я знаю **всё, что** ты не знаешь!*

1. Это СПП с придаточным **местоименно-определительным**, местоименная  связь, ЧТО — союзное слово, не союз. Местоименная пара все — что.

Этот **вид придаточных** указан еще  в 1987 году с Справочнике Баранова М.Т. Например: ***Кто** с пользою отечеству трудится, **Тот** с ним легко не разлучится.* Там рекомендованы вопросы: тот — кто именно?
Тогда мы зададим **вопрос: всё — что именно?**

Хотя есть и **другое мнение**: Как и придаточные определительные, местоименно-определительные придаточные раскрывают признак предмета (поэтому к ним лучше тоже задавать вопрос **какой?**) и присоединяются к главному предложению с помощью союзных слов (основные союзные слова — кто и что). Но такой вопрос звучит неестественно. Так что вопрос **дискуссионный.** Может, лучше вообще не надо задавать к этим придаточным вопросы.

**Примечание (о местоимении ВСЁ)**

Местоимение ВСЁ является характерным отличительным **признаком** именно **местоименно-определительных** придаточных. (Подобрать парный вариант с изъяснительным придаточным очень затруднительно). Местоимение ВСЁ с предметным значением (местоименное существительное) **определяется** придаточным, которое называет его признак (**КАКОЕ именно** из значений этого местоимения имеется в виду). Ведь это местоимение **многозначное** по словарю, его можно отнести к словам с **неопределенным** значением, которым требуется определение.

2. В общем случае местоименно-определительные придаточные занимают **переходную зону** между изъяснительной и местоименной связью. Поэтому часто требуется **сравнительный анализ.**

Сравнить: Я знаю **все, чего** ты не знаешь. Я знаю **всех, кого** ты не знаешь. Это признаки местоименной связи (**замена** союзного слова). Придаточное не передает **содержание** знания (что), а только **характеризует** его.

**Примечание**. Этот анализ взят из "Синтаксиса современного русского языка". Учебник для педвузов.

Также: *Я знаю **всё то**, что ты не знаешь! Я знаю **то, что ты** не знаешь.* Это тоже местоименно-определительные придаточные.

3. Сравним **два вида придаточных с местоименной парой то — что:**

(1) *Я знаю **то*** (= тот материал), ***что*** ты еще не выучил (местоименно-определительное, характеристика знания). Указательное слово **обязательно**, убрать его нельзя.

(2) *Я знаю **то, что** (ты еще не выучил **урок**)* (изъяснительное, содержание знания). Обратим внимание: ЧТО — союз, не союзное слово/дополнение. Прямое дополнение **урок** там уже есть. Указательное слово **факультативно**, его можно убрать.

Comment: «_Анализ взят из "Синтаксиса современного русского языка". Учебник для педвузов, не для школы._» === Есть  и у Литневской в школьном учебнике: http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#42101

Comment: А там есть сравнительный АНАЛИЗ двух видов связи (местоименной и изъяснительной)?

Comment: В разделе о придаточных изъяснительных при разборе одного из примеров есть примерно то, что и у Кустовой: «_Такие придаточные относятся именно к указательному слову, в качестве которого может выступать только слово **то.**. Эта особенность сближает такие предложения с местоименно-определительными, использование же союза, а не союзного слова позволяет отнести их к изъяснительным_».  У нас же – союзное слово и придаточное определительное…

Comment: Хорошо, что есть. Но различить два вида предложений не всегда просто. Мне нравится объяснение темы у Кустовой, оно вполне доступное и понятное как для школьников, так и для студентов.

Comment: ТО есть вопрос совсем не важен?

Comment: @sharon И можете объяснить? Что значит переходного типа? Однозначный ответ есть?

Comment: Переходная зона – это условное название. В этом случае сложно различаются два вида придаточных, но различить их нужно однозначно. Поэтому  требуется дополнительная проверка. Пара местоимений ТО – ЧТО может относиться к обоим видам. Предлагается две проверки: А) замена ТО на ВСЕ; б) замена ЧТО на КОГО. Это признаки местоименной связи. Как мы видим, в нашем варианте уже есть «всё», поэтому и проверять не надо: у нас однозначно местоименная связь.

Comment: Можно посмотреть в учебнике на стр.193  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf  Это 2005 год, у меня 2013 год. В ответе я дополнительно указываю формальные признаки различения, но это для пары ТО - ЧТО. В этом случае различить сложнее, но различать нужно.

Comment: @Sharon Cпасибо. А можете еще подсказать, будет союз в этой фразе или союзное слово? Как их отличить?Мне достаточно было того, что я  узнал эту новость от вас.

Comment: Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. ТОГО – указательное слово, ЧТО – союз, было достаточно (чего?) – вопрос задается от сказуемого. Сравнить: Мне достаточно было того, что я узнал от вас. Это союзное слово в местоименном придаточном.

Comment: Очень запутанно. А почему во втором случае вопрос не от глагола задать?

Comment: Вопрос тоже от глагола. Но теперь речь идет о самой новости. Мне достаточно было (чего?)  того (той новости), что (которую) я узнал от вас.

Comment: А разве можно подменять другими словами?

Comment: Я не меняю, а поясняю.  ТО /ТОГО - местоименное существительное, сама новость.  ТО = та новость. ЧТО можно заменить словом КОТОРЫЙ. Почему так?  Сравните: Дом, что строится...  Дом, который строится.  ЧТО = КОТОРЫЙ (для местоименной связи).

Answer (score 2):

Второй ответ (по комментариям)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ТЕМЕ**: Какой вопрос следует задать к придаточному и как это придаточное можно квалифицировать в рамках школьной программы?

Ответ на этот вопрос есть [**в учебнике Литневской** (учебный комплекс 1 и 3)](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm)

...Поскольку более распространенной в практике школьного и довузовского преподавания является классификация, принятая **в комплексах 1 и 3,** обратимся именно к ней.

...Кроме того, существуют придаточные определительные предложения, относящиеся именно к указательным или определительным местоимениям ***тот, то, таков, такой, каждый, весь, всякий*** и др., которые не могут быть опущены. Такие придаточные называются **местоименно-определительными.** Отличие придаточных местоименно-определительных от **собственно определительных** заключается и в их способности располагаться перед главной частью.  В комплексе 2  соответственно придаточные определительное и сказуемное.

Какой вопрос нужно задать?  Ответ можно найти в учебных методических материалах [**Виды придаточных предложений – таблица**](https://vpr-ege.ru/oge/russkij-yazyk/1074-vidy-pridatochnykh-predlozhenij)

**Местоименно-определительные:**

**Какой именно?**   К местоимению в значении существительного   Союзные слова: кто,  что и др.

**РАЗБОР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ (из комментариев)**

1. Разберем предложение:  *Мне достаточно было **того, что** (я узнал эту новость от вас).*

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. ТОГО – указательное слово, ЧТО – союз, было достаточно (чего?) — вопрос задается от сказуемого.

Это предложение **не так просто** разобрать школьникам, если они только начали проходить эту тему.

Хотя это изъяснительное предложение, но в грамматике такие предложения   названы так: **приместоименные изъяснительные** придаточные (вмещающие СПП). Их характерные признаки:  неречевой глагол (достаточно), наличие обязательного местоимения (достаточно ТОГО), союз ЧТО, который «вмещает»  целое предложение: я узнал эту новость от вас.  Такие предложения  считают особым **местоименным видом** изъяснительных предложений.

2. А это уже парный вариант:  *«Мне достаточно было **ТОГО, ЧТО** я узнал от вас»*.

Местоименно-определительное предложение, местоименная пара «того — что». Казалось бы, здесь мало что изменилось, а предложение другого вида. В чем же дело?  Теперь там нет дополнения **«эту новость»**,  а на его месте союзное слово ***ЧТО*** в роли дополнения.

Два характерных **признака** местоименной связи: (1) ЧТО — не  союз, а союзное слово, теперь это **член предложения** (дополнение): узнал что (= новость); (2)  Предложение не будет самодостаточным без этого дополнения, так как оно **участвует** в построении предложения.

3. И делаем **вывод:**

Осваивать тему надо на более простых предложениях, не стоит сразу же приступать к изучению изъяснительных (вмещающих) СПП.