# Ещё раз о типе придаточного

Tags: синтаксис

Натолкнуло меня задать этот вопрос предложение, приведённое в теме

[**Подскажите, какой тип придаточного**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475014/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Насколько я понимаю, тип придаточного должен быть связан с вопросом, на который он отвечает.

Есть следующее предложение:

***Всё, что делается на этом свете, всё прекрасно и умно.***

Какой вопрос следует задать к придаточному и как это придаточное можно квалифицировать в рамках школьной программы?

Comment: @Ajgy, срок конкурса подходит к концу, других ответов я, похоже, не дождусь. Я принимаю Ваш ответ, но, пожалуйста, уберите, когда вернётесь на сайт, своё добавление к ответу, начиная со слов «НИКАКИХ МЕСТОИМЕННО-СООТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИДАТОЧНЫХ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ...». Всё-таки, терминов на белом свете много, и этот тоже существует. Я бы и сам откорректировал Ваш ответ, но мне это пока по статусу не позволено: моя правка «**будет поставлена в очередь, пока не пройдёт экспертную проверку**»…

Answer (score 3):

**ПОСЛЕСЛОВИЕ К ЗАДАННОМУ МНОЙ ВОПРОСУ**

На этом сайте бо́льшая часть ответов школьникам о виде придаточных даётся с опорой на институтские учебники (в частности, на учебник Кустовой). Захотелось разобраться, насколько классификация придаточных в школьных учебниках соответствует классификации, изучаемой в институтах, и можно ли, не зная, по какому конкретно учебнику учится ученик, дать ему *правильный* ответ, потому и открыл эту тему.

К сожалению, она вызвала не очень большой интерес у наших любителей русского языка.

Просмотрел основные учебники, используемые в школах в настоящее время:

1. **Русский язык**. 9-й класс : учебник / С. Г. Бархударов, С. Е. Крючков, Л. Ю. Максимов [и др.].  — М., 2023;
2. **Русский язык**. 9-й класс : учебник / М. М. Разумовская, С. И. Львова, В. И.  Капинос, В. В. Львов. — М., 2022;
3. **Русский язык**. Теория : 5—9-e классы : углублённое изучение : учебник / В. В. Бабайцева. — М., 2022.

Термин ***местоименно-определительное***, которым можно было бы охарактеризовать рассматриваемое предложение, присутствует **только** в первом учебнике.

Учащиеся по второму учебнику это предложение назвали бы, наверное, просто ***определительным***. В этом учебнике дано примечание, что «такие предложения некоторые учёные называют *местоименно-соотносительными*. <…> В главной части таких предложений обязательно употребляется местоимение, а придаточная часть конкретизирует значение этого местоимения и отвечает на вопросы *кто именно? что именно?*».

Ну а учащиеся по учебнику [3] не станут называть рассматриваемое предложение *определительным*. В из учебнике используется классическая (традиционная) классификация придаточных предложений, в которой придаточные соотносятся с членами предложения. В ней выделяются придаточные ***подлежащные, сказуемные, дополнительные, определительные, обстоятельственные*** (разных видов), ***присоединительные***. И хоть в этой классификации имеют место и *определительные* придаточные, рассматриваемое нами придаточное в их число не попадёт, т. к. раскрывает содержание **местоимения**, а не **существительного**, что требуется для придаточных определительных в этой
классификации.

По учебнику [3] — придаточное ***подлежащное***.

Вот как разбирает рассматриваемое нами предложение **Вера Васильевна Бабайцева** в своём пособии «Анализ слова и предложения» (М., 2014):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

Похоже на то, что даже *правильные* ответы, прозвучавшие в этой теме в ответах и комментариях, могут оказаться совершенно *неправильными*, если ими воспользуется ученик, учащийся по другому, нежели рассчитывали отвечавшие, учебнику.

Comment: В каждом конкретном случае надо ориентироваться на учебник данной школы.

Answer (score 1):

***Всë, что делается на этом свете, — всë прекрасно и умно.***

Здесь обязательно ставить именно запятую и тире, сейчас объясню почему.

Объяснение одно и довольно краткое: если  в сложном предложении есть повторяющееся слово в разных придаточных частях, то ставится запятая и тире. Здесь повторяющееся слово — ***всë***.

Ещë пример предложения:

*И только родная мама, которая с самого рождения чувствует тебя лучше, чем ты сам, которая не спала ночами, которая всегда поможет, подскажет и поддержит в трудную минуту, — только мама всегда будет рядом*. Здесь повторяющееся слово — ***мама***.

Так что в этом предложении единственный вариант, как расставить знаки препинания.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как расставить знаки препинания, а в том, какой тип придаточного.

Comment: @Серж,  а как вы определите грамматику всего этого предложения?

Comment: @Sharon, местоименно-определительное.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж.  Я тоже так считаю.

Answer (score 0):

Это определительное придаточное. Вопрос задаем от местоимения:

**все** (какое) ***,что делается на этом свете.***

---

Для проверки может использовать способ замены:

Все, **которое** делается на этом свете, все прекрасно и умно.

Или

**Чучело** (какое), **которое** делается на этом свете, прекрасно и умно.

---

**НИКАКИХ МЕСТОИМЕННО-СООТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИДАТОЧНЫХ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ.** Выдумки лингвистов нужны только для углубленного изучения недр лингвистики. Для того, чтобы описать все сложноподчиненные предложения русского языка, будет достаточно основной классификации, закрепленной в кодификаторе ФИПИ.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Ajgy**, я отметил уже два дня назад плюсом Ваш ответ. Наверное, в каких-то школах это придаточное так и называют. Может, что и в большинстве школ, но вряд ли во всех. А ещё какие-нибудь варианты названий могут быть у этого придаточного?

Comment: Так принято во всей школьной практике. ОГЭ и ЕГЭ придерживается такой же схемы.  Есть только три типа: обстоятельственное, изъяснительное и определительное. В программе вуза называют их местоименно-соотносительными.

Comment: «_ОГЭ и ЕГЭ придерживается такой же схемы._» === Просмотрел сейчас типовые экзаменационные варианты ЕГЭ по русскому за 2018 год (сборник под ред. Цыбулько). Вопросов, связанных с классификацией придаточных, там не нашёл. Может, ЕГЭ и ОГЭ обходят этот вопрос стороной?

Comment: @Слава,  а в чем  трудность? Это местоименно-определительное предложения. В школьной программе этот тип предложения относится к определительным придаточным предложениям.

Comment: @Серж А в каком учебном комплексе (1, 2, 3)?  В двух (1 и 3) выделяют местоименно-определительные предложения по отношению к собственно определительным (большинство школ) . А не выделяют (по Литневской) только в комплексе 2.

Comment: @Слава В ОГЭ есть такая тема, но там не говорится ни о каких "местоименно-соотносительных" придаточных. Сохраняется тройственная структура: определительное, изъяснительное, обстоятельственное. Смотреть нужно на кодификатор, а не на всякий ширпотреб - комплексы и методички. Дополняю свой ответ этой информацией.

Comment: @Ajgy: «_В ОГЭ есть такая тема…_» ===  Чем это утверждение можно было бы подтвердить?

Comment: @Sharon, насколько мне известно, других комплексов нет. Вот еще материал. https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/739-223_pridatochnye_podlezhaschnye.html    https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/739-223_pridatochnye_podlezhaschnye.html

Comment: @Серж Существует много классификаций СПП, и это понятно: в основе любой классификации лежит какой-либо фактор. Поэтому предлагаются такие  классификации:  научная (для специалистов), вузовская (учебная для фил. и пед. факультетов), школьная (учебная, в нескольких вариантах по уровню сложности) .  Все это надо знать и учитывать, причем  не своему усмотрению, а на основе источников.

Comment: Вот пример: местоименно-соотносительные предложения —  вузовский вариант, местоименно-определительные  (как разновидность определительных) — школьный вариант средней сложности (практически во всех учебниках ), только определительные  — упрощенный школьный вариант.  А  что в вопросах по ОГЭ и ЕГЭ?  В учебных пособиях я вообще не вижу, чтобы на экзамене об этом были вопросы.  Эти темы, конечно, изучаются, но выносятся ли СПП такого вида на экзамен? В предлагаемых текстах вроде бы обычные определительные предложения.

Comment: @Sharon, мне тоже не попадались на экзамене эти вопросы.

Comment: @Ajgy, **срок конкурса подходит к концу**, других ответов я, похоже, не дождусь. Я приму Ваш ответ, но, **пожалуйста, уберите перед этим своё добавление к ответу, начиная со слов** «НИКАКИХ МЕСТОИМЕННО-СООТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИДАТОЧНЫХ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ...». Всё-таки, терминов на белом свете много, и этот тоже существует. Я  бы и сам откорректировал Ваш ответ, но мне это пока по статусу не позволено: моя правка «**будет поставлена в очередь, пока не пройдёт экспертную проверку**». А пройдёт ли она за оставшиеся 3 часа эту проверку или вообще никогда не пройдёт –  я никак повлиять на результат не могу…

Comment: @Ajgy, **пожалуйста**, уберите своё добавление к ответу, начиная со слов «НИКАКИХ МЕСТОИМЕННО-СООТНОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПРИДАТОЧНЫХ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ...». На мой взгляд, это **неправильное** заявление, а признав Ваш ответ лучшим, получается, что я согласился и с этим заявлением?