# Вид и вопрос придаточного предложения

Tags: спп, сложное-предложение

Прошу вас помочь разобраться с грамматическим **разбором** предложения:

*Кому приходилось странствовать по тайге, **тот знает**, что значит во время непогоды найти зверовую фанзу.*

Непонятно, какой **вопрос** нужно задать от главного к придаточному (кому приходилось странствовать по тайге)?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Artur. А Вы сами как думаете? Как ответите на свои вопросы и почему именно так? Всё это желательно написать в поле вопроса. Тогда Вам укажут на ошибки, если они будут.

Comment: Кстати, задать вопрос к такому  придаточному не так просто. Это обсуждалось на форуме в двух темах  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475014/Подскажите-какой-тип-придаточного   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475016/Ещё-раз-о-типе-придаточного   Есть ответ и в учебном пособии  https://vpr-ege.ru/oge/russkij-yazyk/1074-vidy-pridatochnykh-predlozhenij

Answer (score 2):

***Кому** приходилось странствовать по тайге, **тот знает**, **что** значит во время непогоды найти зверовую фанзу.*

1. СПП с двумя придаточными, **параллельное** подчинение. Главное предложение: ***тот знает***.
2. Придаточное **местоименно-определительное**:  тот (кто именно? какой именно?), *кому приходилось странствовать по тайге.* Связь **местоименная** (тот — с. с. кому), **инверсия** придаточного (находится перед главным).
3. Придаточное **изъяснительное**: знает (что?), *чтО значит во время непогоды найти зверовую фанзу*. ***ЧТО*** — союзное слово в роли дополнения (***чтО*** значит).

**Сравнить**: Найти фанзу значит (что?) многое.

4. **Схема**: (с. с. кому), [**тот знает**], (с. с. что).

Comment: Ответ никому не нравится, в том числе автору вопроса. И ни одного комментария.  Что-нибудь не так с грамматикой или с заданным вопросом?  Тогда я лучше послушаю другие ответы, чтобы сравнить. Может, что исправлю.

Comment: Возвращаю ответ на место. Никто не отвечает, советоваться не с кем. Пусть хотя бы люди читают…

Comment: А вы, что, удаляли свой ответ? Шарон, если нет комментарий, значит и сказать нечего. Все нормально. Лично мне писать тяжело с телефона. Поэтому часто не отвечаю. Но всегда голосую за ваши ответы.

Comment: Серж, там неоднозначная тема (вопрос к местоименно-определительному придаточному). Помните, сколько мы его обсуждали? Я не знаю, насколько корректен мой ответ – все же молчат. Хотя бы комментарий кто написал: все верно. Спасибо вам за голосование! Поддержка коллектива всем нужна,  и я тут не исключение.

Comment: Всё верно. Плюс был 14 часов назад :)  Поставил себя на место спрашивающего и вспомнил первую встречу со всеми этими СПП, ДО, с. с.

Comment: Спасибо за плюс.  А что за первая встреча, обсуждение в сентябре?  Кстати, сколько было внимания к теме)) А здесь предложение посложнее будет. У меня еще были сомнения со вторым придаточным:  с.с.   ЧТО – подлежащее  или дополнение.

Comment: Первая встреча с сокращениями, мне незнакомыми. // Про сентябрь напомните? // Подлежащее. А само предложение -- дополнение к глаголу в ГП. Изъяснительное дополнительное.

Comment: Думаете, что подлежащее?  Я сначала тоже так написала, а потом исправила. И что же это?  У меня подлежащее – найти.

Comment: Да, дополнение, *найти* подлежащее.

Comment: Изъяснительное дополнительное? Если только для школьников из 2-го учебного комплекса. У Кустовой такого не увидишь.  Систематизация должна быть корректной, однозначной и серьезной, а не описательной (как бы с разных точек зрения).  С одной стороны дополнительное, а в целом само по себе. Тм еще вмещающие изъяснительные есть,  всем вместе тесновато будет.