# Союз или нет? Чем является «что»?

Tags: союзы, подлежащее, относительные-местоимения

`Несмотря на то, что он сказал...`

`Независимо от того, что он сделал...`

`Вопреки тому, что говорится в интернете...`

`Из-за того, что ты сделал...`

`Вследствие того, что нам пришлось сделать...`

Мне кажется, что слова: *несмотря на то что*; *независимо от того, что*; *вопреки тому, что*; *из-за того, что*; *вследствие того, что* — никак не могут быть союзами. Сочетание предлога, местоимения и относительного местоимения. А слово *что* есть подлежащее?

Comment: Прекрасный вопрос!  Мне пришлось подумать (сначала пропустила вариант с изъяснительным придаточным),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ***ЧТО*** — местоименная часть союза ***НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО*** с уступительным значением: ***Несмотря на то, что** он сказал...*
2. ***ЧТО*** — союзное слово в местоименно-определительном придаточном в роли дополнения, ударная позиция:

*Независимо от того, ***чтО*** он сделал...*

*Вопреки тому, ***чтО*** говорится в интернете...*

*Из-за того, ***чтО*** ты сделал...*

Вследствие того, ***чтО*** нам пришлось сделать...

3. ***ЧТО*** —  союз в изъяснительном придаточном,  безударная позиция:

*Независимо от того, ***что*** он сделал...*

*Из-за того, ***что*** ты сделал...*

*Вследствие того, ***что*** нам пришлось сделать...*

Comment: А может ли оно быть подлежащим? _Несмотря на то, что он сделал_: _он сделал (что?) что_.

Comment: Но там есть подлежащее "он".

Comment: Ой... Туплю... Дополнением, вот что я хотел сказать.

Comment: Будьте внимательны сэр.  Вы очень спешите, а редакторы не дремлют))

Comment: Так что, дополнение или нет? Вопрос к нему задается.

Comment: Максим, посмотрите мой ответ. Там написано, когда ЧТО является дополнением. Вы его вообще-то читали, всё там понимаете?  Метод вопросов мне тоже не нравится)) Нужен грамматический анализ.

Comment: Возможно, я тоже могу ошибиться, не надо считать, что у меня нет права на ошибку. А как и кто принимает – это личное дело участника. Редакторы же исправляют пропущенные буквы и т. д.  Я только это хотела сказать, не более того. Да и ответ дала через час после того, как он был задан. Не очень спешно, как мне думается. У вас и у других участников было время, чтобы предложить свои варианты.

Comment: Но, может, вы и правы, пора мне и помолчать. А ответы давать через пару дней, когда уж все выскажутся.  Так оно удобнее: послушал, посмотрел, ошибки нашел, вот ты и лучше всех.  Есть. правда, еще вариант: не браться за сложные вопросы, ведь очки и на простых можно заработать, причем без особого труда и без лишней затраты времени. И опять молодец.

Comment: Слава, я ничего не считаю, зачем вы спрашиваете меня об этом?  Извините, но я не понимаю ваш месседж.  Вы можете ответить на любой закрытый вопрос, я часто так делаю.  (То есть когда у вас будет время,) Приемка не так уж важна, если  вам есть чем дополнить ответ.  Если у вас такие необыкновенные знания, то почему бы вам не поделиться с нами.  Я считаю, что это хороший вопрос, но у вас может быть другое мнение.   зачем же нам спорить?  И не стоит ПРЕНЕБРЕЖИТЕЛЬНО отзываться ни о чем (ни о людях, ни о форуме, ни о вопросах/ответах).

Comment: Только вот эти простые вряд ли можно найти теперь, их только ждать надо. По старым вопросам (я листал их) я понял, что мы здесь дплеко не первые и что активность была намного выше. Несколько десятков, а то и сотен тысяч, а то и больше просмотров. Даже если легкий вопрос найдем, вряд ли участник его примет, потому что он уже давно не заходит сюда.

Comment: А сейчас даже 100 просмотров очень сложно набрать.

Comment: @Sharon Таким образом, при разграничении соза от союзного слова требуется в первую очередь обращать внимание на логическое ударение в этой части в контексте конкретеного предложения. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: В этих предложениях да.  Но вот другое предложение: Я знаю всё, что ТЫ не знаешь! Там в ударной позиции находится подлежащее, а дополнение безударное.  Но это союзное слово. Здесь основной критерий такой:  ЧТО - это единственное дополнение, а оно здесь необходимо.  Сравнить: Мне достаточно было того, что (я узнал эту новость от вас). Изъяснительное, союз ЧТО. Мне достаточно было того, чтО я узнал от вас». Местоименная связь. Посмотрите эту тему, ее долго обсуждали https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475014/Подскажите-какой-тип-придаточного