какой вид придаточного?
я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем отдать поклон народу-труженнику
«чтобы всем отдать поклон народу-труженнику» какой это вид придаточного?
изъяснительное или все-таки местоименно-определительное?
скорее придерживаюсь к тому варианту, что это изъяснительное, потому что мы видим здесь глагол состояния,речи,мысли и чувств.
я немного сократила это предложение.оно звучит так:
я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем, что писал и напишу, отдать поклон этому народу-труженнику, народу-строителю, народу-герою
«что писал и напишу» это придаточное местоименно-определительное, так как оно относится к местоимению «всем», вроде как…
скорректируйте меня, если я не права)
ПРОШУ НЕ ПИСАТЬ САМЫМ УМНЫМ ЛЮДЯМ НА ПЛАНЕТЕ,ЧТО МОЙ ТЕКСТ НУЖНО ЦЕЛИКОМ КОРРЕКТИРОВАТЬ.Я УЧУСЬ В 9 КЛАССЕ И ПЫТАЮСЬ РАЗОБРАТЬСЯ В ГРАММАТИКЕ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА,ЗАДАЮ ЗДЕСЬ ИНТЕРЕСУЮЩИЕ МЕНЯ ВОПРОСЫ.ЕСЛИ ВАМ НЕЧЕГО ОТВЕТИТЬ НА МОЙ ВОПРОС,ТО Я БОЛЬШЕ НЕ ЖДУ НИКАКИХ КОММЕНТАРИЕВ В СВОЮ СТОРОНУ,СПАСИБО.

Синтаксический разбор:
Я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем  творчеством отдать поклон народу-труженику.
Ну очень сложный разбор! (Возможно, он факультативный для школы.)

Это особая конструкция, которая называется так: Приместоименные изъяснительные придаточные (вмещающие СПП). В них есть изъяснительная часть, как в обычном изъяснительном СПП, но относится она не к глаголу (существительному) со значением мысли/речи, а к указательному местоимению.

Такое местоимение является обязательным в отличие от обычных изъяснительных СПП, где оно факультативно. ЧТОБЫ — это изъяснительный союз. На местоименно-определительное придаточное такое СПП  похоже вопросом: состоит в чем именно?

Другой вариант с союзом ЧТО: Моя задача состоит в том, что я должен всем  творчеством отдать поклон народу-труженику.

Сравнить с обычным СПП с изъяснительным придаточным: Я знаю, что всем творчеством я должен отдать поклон народу-труженику.


В виде БСП для проверки: Я знаю: всем творчеством я должен отдать поклон народу-труженику.

Сравнить с СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным: Я знаю то, что является основной задачей писателя. Это  отдать поклон народу-труженику. Изъяснительной части нет, но есть ее вступительная характеристика.

Я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем, что писал и напишу, отдать поклон этому народу-труженику, народу-строителю, народу-герою.


Всем, что писал и напишу... Это действительно местоименно-определительное придаточное, есть местоименная пара всем — что.

и все-таки между этими видами придаточных есть какая-то тонкая грань, которую я не улавливаю. «я знаю то,что является…» по характеристикам из интернета относится к изъяснительным, потому что есть глагол мысли «знаю». еще пишут, что их можно различить по союзам, так как в придаточном местоименно-определительном они не используются. но я задавала вопрос ранее и мы выяснили, что и такой вариант возможен. если разницы нет ни в глаголах, ни в союзах тогда в чем она выражается?….

Sharon, помнится, вы ещё раз писали про разницу между этими двумя типами придаточных.

Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

@Серж, спасибо!.  Была у нас тема: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475014/Подскажите-какой-тип-придаточного Во втором ответе был разобран дополнительный пример: Мне достаточно было того, что (я узнал эту новость от вас). Это изъясн. вмещающее. Парный вариант: «Мне достаточно было ТОГО, ЧТО я узнал от вас». Это мест.-определит.

Аполлинария: "Я знаю то, что является основной задачей писателя".  Местоим. -опред.придаточное. Здесь ЧТО является подлежащим в придаточном (не союз в изъясн.), поэтому это с.с.  Надо учитывать все признаки, и в первую очередь роль местоимения ЧТО.

Об оформлении вопросов
На сайте существует определенный стандарт оформления вопросов, и наши участники иногда редактируют их, чтобы сделать более понятными.  В принципе в данном случае не совсем корректно делать новому участнику замечания, а лучше предложить свою правку. Я бы записала вопрос так:

Я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем отдать поклон народу-труженику.

Какой это вид придаточного, изъяснительное или все-таки местоименно-определительное? Я считаю, что это скорее изъяснительное, потому что мы видим здесь глагол состояния, речи, мысли и чувства.

Я немного сократила это предложение, оно звучит так:

Я видел и вижу свою задачу как писателя в том, чтобы всем, что писал и напишу, отдать поклон этому народу-труженику, народу-строителю, народу-герою.
«...что писал и напишу» — это придаточное местоименно-определительное, так как оно относится к местоимению «всем». Скорректируйте меня, если я не права)
P. S.  А это немного юмора на тему прописных букв, которую мы обсуждали на форуме. Улыбнитесь, пожалуйста)
О прописных буквах. Эстетика, логика и даже Хармс

благодарю вас! честно, если бы мне сразу так написали, то у меня бы и мысли не возникло писать что-то «агрессивное» в ответ) я хорошо отношусь к тому, чтобы меня исправили в случае чего. я только за, потому что люблю учиться новому. но вот этот комментарий, непонятно с какой претензией мне не очень понравился, поэтому я и высказалась)) еще раз спасибо!

Не усложняйте и не подменяйте проблему, Sharon, говоря о неких стандартах сайта. Речь была лишь об элементарном, общепринятом и доступном всякому школьнику.

Это новый участник, поэтому объясняйте ваши элементарные стандарты вежливо,  без неуместных оценочных сравнений. Я же говорю о своем понимании темы, связанной с оформлением вопросов. В любом случае я с большим вниманием выслушаю мнение модераторов об этой ситуации.  На сайте часто редактируют вопросы,  но почему-то в данном случае  никто не предложил правку.
